# Why does the variable replace not evaluate to 13168375?

Tags: javascript, regex, if-statement, for-loop

```
var counts = [ "TION 13168375", "IONT 11234972", "THER 10218035", "THAT 8980536"];

var replace = 0
var scored = 0
var qgram = ""
function score(ciphertext) {
qgram = ciphertext
for (var a=0;a<counts.length;a++){
    console.log(counts[a].substring(0,4))
    if(counts[a].substring(0,4)==qgram){
        console.log("t")
        replace = parseInt(counts[a].replace(/[^1-9]/g),"");
        scored+=Math.log(replace/4600000000)*Math.LOG10E
    }
}
}
score("TION")
```

When I run the code the "t" shows up indicating that the if statement works but the variable replace is NaN, why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem in with `parseInt(counts[a].replace(/[^1-9]/g`**`)`**`,""`**`)`**`;`, you missed a semicolon. It should be like this:

`parseInt(counts[a].replace(/[^1-9]/g, ""`**`))`**`;`

Your code still works because [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) can be given a second argument, which defines radix of number, but this behaviour is wrong in your case.

Another thing I have noticed is that you're setting the value of `replace` each time the condition matches. This can turn out to work incorrect in case `counts` happens to contain multiple elements that matches `counts[a].substring(0, 4) === qgram` condition.

---

*Suggestion:* Do not group calls like this, it's a big [Anti pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern). It doesn't really help with anything except produces few bytes less in source file, but it's not worth it.

*Also*, I'd suggest you to use semicolons (`;`) at end of each line, the code is readable much faster this way, you don't have to look if it wraps to next line.

Code after applying these suggestions:

```
var counts = ["TION 13168375", "IONT 11234972", "THER 10218035", "THAT 8980536"];

var replace = 0;
var scored = 0;
var qgram = "";

function score(ciphertext) {
    replace = []; // reset the array when calling the function
    qgram = ciphertext;
    for (var a = 0; a < counts.length; a++) {
        console.log(counts[a].substring(0, 4));
        if (counts[a].substring(0, 4) === qgram) {
            console.log("t");
            var tmp = counts[a].replace(/[^1-9]/g, "");
            replace = parseInt(tmp);
            scored += Math.log(replace / 4600000000) * Math.LOG10E;
        }
    }
}
score("TION");
```

If really can't stand JavaScript syntax, you can use [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/), which has syntax similar to ruby/python and transcompiles to JavaScript.

---

*Another suggestion:* I've noticed you're using `.replace(/[^1-9]/g, "")`, which is regex to match all characters that aren't numbers and replace them with empty string (i.e. remove them). Problem here is that it could match any numbers in text, which might break the functionality of your code in case of left side containing any numbers.

I see that your form is pretty constant, so you could use:

```
// split into array, ex. ['TION', '13168375']
var tmp = counts[a].split(' ')[1]; // gets the second element = '13168375'
replace = parseInt(tmp);
```

This works much faster than regexes (~2.5x faster) and it's also more proof to different descriptions.

Even better solution would be use of `JavaScript object`, could be inside code, or even better, as separate `json` file.

---

*Optimisation:* The `scored` equation is almost constant, the only variable used is `replace`, which is parsed from your data. You could calculate these values in advance, e.g. at first run of the script (script initialisation) and parse the calculated value instead. The way it's called now, it produces unnecessary CPU load.

---

I know that I've put too much text on here, saying you should do this and that instead. I do not intend to diss your code, I'd just like to help you get better at coding, one suggestion at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Break up your code and step through it:

```
replace = parseInt(counts[a].replace(/[^1-9]/g), "")
```

Can become:

```
var s = "TION 13168375";
var r = s.replace(/[^1-9]/g);
var replace = parseInt(r, "");
```

That probably isn't doing what you want it to do. Your `replace()` statement doesn't have a defined value with which to replace the values it finds, and `parseInt()`'s second value is a radix. A blank string isn't a radix. It looks like you have a parens in the wrong spot.